# How to retrive 3rd party reques's hostname/dns in API Request in C#

Tags: twilio

in my application i had implimented twilio SMS Send and Receive function, which is working well, now i When twilio Send me sms i need to take from which domain name or host name twilio call my api. i want to enable cors for perticular server. 
I tried following code but it's provide me my own Machine name.

```
var addlist = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
string GetHostName = addlist.HostName.ToString();
```

This code give me my server Name like - myPc-xx.com
But i want the API call from www.Twilio.com/sds

can any one help me for the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will want to reference the Twilio [Security](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security) webpage, which provides two ways to authenticate the inbound webhooks to your web application. Twilio uses [dynamic based infrastructure](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183868-Which-IP-addresses-will-Twilio-s-requests-come-from-), so there is not a fixed FQDN webhooks originate from.